# Preferred/Idiomatic method to enable a systemd.service from a Debian package installation

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I have a custom Debian package I've built for our software that creates a systemd service. What is the preferred/idiomatic way to have the installation of said package enable/start the service at install time?

What I did was add the following three lines to my `postinst` script:

```
systemctl --system daemon-reload
systemctl enable my_service.service
systemctl start my_service.service
```

This worked fine until we tried to include loading this package in our initial image creation running under `debootstrap` at which point it turned out that `systemctl` appears to want a lot of environment stuff set up that just isn't normally up in that process.

Comment: I have a similar question related to RPMs. I eventually gave up trying to start the system from the RPM post install script, because the way yum upgrade works: it first installs the new package, then uninstalls the old package. That means that the service is started, then stopped if you do an upgrade!

Comment: @MarkLakata thanks for the heads up, you potentially saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at a similar situation, I want to configure services in a debootstrap rootfs.  It seems `systemctl enable` simply reads the targets in the `[Install]` section of a unit file and creates the correct symlinks.  So if you know what services you want to start under which targets, I think the correct answer might be to just create the correct symlinks.  e.g.

```
ln -s /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ssh.service \
      /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service
```

The other two steps (`daemon-reload` and `start`) you don't want to do when installing into a debootstrap chroot, but then I guess your problem is how to just do the symlink when in the debootstrap env and the normal way otherwise....

#### Edit for debootstrap

As it happens I'm also using `debootstrap` and I've found `systemctl enable` calls work fine so long as the calling user is `root` (to avoid the  `Failed to connect to bus` warning.)  `daemon-reload` and `start` probably don't make sense during an install under chroot since you're not in a live environment.  So your `postinst` probably wants to detect chroot and skip those lines. Or set an env variable or pass some flag that your installer script can read.

```
IM_DEBOOTSTRAPPING=yes dpkg -i mypackage.deb  # tells postinst to skip systemctl start
```