# Installing a systemd service from an RPM?

Tags: linux, rpm, systemd

I've been creating RPMS (using CMake's CPack) which install everything into `/opt`, and then the postinstall script copies the service definition files to `/etc/systemd/system`.

I've toyed around with starting and stopping the services as well in the RPM postinstall and preuninstall scripts, but this doesn't seem to be a good idea, because `yum` will run the postinstall script before the preuninstall script if doing an upgrade, and that means that if you try to upgrade a service, you end up with the service not running anyways.  Even enable/disable seems to have the same issue.

So the two questions I have

1. Is it a good idea to install directly into `/etc/systemd`, or should a postinstall copy from `/opt` to `/etc/systemd`? Is `cp` followed by `systemctl daemon-reload` the "right" way of installing the service file?
2. Is there a clean way of `starting/stopping/enable/disable` services from an RPM, or is this better left out of the RPM?

Related question (with no answers) for Debian:

[Preferred/Idiomatic method to enable a systemd.service from a Debian package installation](https://superuser.com/questions/836353/preferred-idiomatic-method-to-enable-a-systemd-service-from-a-debian-package-ins)

Comment: I believe that in RPM-based distributions, it is frowned upon to ship (or copy) files in /etc. Instead, you should ship them into /lib/systemd. This way, your users can change the files by copying them to /etc, without losing changes on upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

See:
  https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_systemd

In scriptlets you can use $1 variable for detecting if it is upgrade or clean install or upgrade or removal of package. The value of the variable is defined here:
https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/#_syntax